# Properly enable a systemd service - fail2ban

Tags: systemd

In all honesty, I don't feel comfortable at all using systemd. I just can't understand it.

I was using a version of fail2ban that was behaving strangely in my Ubuntu 16.04.
I removed it:

```
apt remove fail2ban
```

and installed the last one:

```
wget https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/archive/0.11.zip
unzip 0.11.zip
cd fail2ban-0.11
python setup.py install
```

At the end of its installation it said I had to enable its service.

I thought that

```
systemctl enable fail2ban.service
```

was enough, but it seemed like the service was "masked".
I used this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/710420/why-are-some-systemd-services-in-the-masked-state
to understand what masked is.

I tried to unmask it:
`systemctl unmask fail2ban.servic`e

and to enable it:

```
systemctl enable fail2ban.service
```

And now the classical command:

```
service fail2ban status | start | stop
```

is working.

**The problem is**, I read I should be able to get info of the service from systemctl too:

```
systemctl fail2ban status
Unknown operation fail2ban.
```

So I started googling results ...
I found this command (and I added | sort for a better output):

```
systemctl list-units | sort
```

That shows:

```
fail2ban.service  loaded active exited  LSB: Start/stop fail2ban
```

I don't know what "exited" meant so I searched:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241970/what-does-status-active-exited-mean-for-a-custom-service

> State active (exited) means that systemd has successfully run the commands but that it does not know there is a daemon to monitor.

**MY request**:

All I wish to do is being able to start and stop and control if it's working, the fail2ban service.
I don't know (almost) anything of systemd because I always skipped it (reason why I moved to Ubuntu 14 after being comfortable with CentOS 5 and previous for years) but it seems I am forced now.

Can someone tell me how I should "add" fail2ban service to systemctl in the proper way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Muscle memory is a thing. The designers of the systemctl utility reordered the command line so that it is now (broadly)

```
systemctl <action> <service>
```

rather than what your muscle memory is accustomed to

```
systemctl <service> <action>
```

So, start stop, restart, enable, status etc become

```
systemctl start fail2ban
systemctl stop fail2ban
systemctl restart fail2ban
systemctl enable fail2ban
systemctl status fail2ban
```